# Michael Hartl's Tutorial Chapter 6: Failing Test due to Syntax_error on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

The tests at listing 6.27 are meant to [pass](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users), however I keep getting 13 errors which all quote the same syntax error at me:

```
Syntax Error:       SyntaxError: /home/action/workspace/app/app/models/user.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
```

This is the model which seems to be causing the error, but I don't see anything that's wrong with it:

```
  1  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  2  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  3  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  4  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
  5                         format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
  6                         uniqueness:  {case_sensitive: false} 
  7  end
```

Initially it was saying the error was line 6, unexpected keyword ":" between uniqueness and the open brackets but after some tinkering around, that seems to have stopped.

A number of the questions on SO regarding this chapter seem to stem from the indentation of the tests itself, so for completeness, I'll include them here:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should be present" do
    @user.name = "     "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should not be too long" do
    @user.name = "a" * 51
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should not be too long" do
    @user.email = "a" * 244 + "@example.com"
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end  

  test "email validation should accept valid addresses" do
    valid_addresses = %w[user@example.com USER@foo.COM A_US-ER@foo.bar.org first.last@foo.jp alice+bob@baz.cn]
    valid_addresses.each do |valid_address|
      @user.email = valid_address
      assert @user.valid?, "#{valid_address.inspect} should be valid"
     end
  end

  test "email validation should reject invalid addresses" do
    invalid_addresses = %w[user@example,com user_at_foo.org user.name@example. foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
    invalid_addresses.each do |invalid_address|
      @user.email = invalid_address
      assert_not @user.valid?, "#{invalid_address.inspect} should be invalid"
    end
  end

  test "email addresses should be unique" do
    duplicate_user = @user.dup
    duplicate_user.email = @user.email.upcase
      @user.save
      assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
    end
  end
```

Comment: you're missing a comma after `format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `,` at the end of line 5.

See the code at [Listing 6.24](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users#code-validates_uniqueness_of_email)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: true
end
```